# Callback method on auto rotation, iOS and iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, callback, autorotate

I am working on iPhone game, i was curious to know if there is a call back function tht gets called when the device forces auto rotation on the game, so that i can change the HUD elements.

Or shd i run infinite loop that checks if the app has rotated in a different thread?  problem is i dont think this is an effective way.  Does anyone have any good solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, as long as the device is not orientation locked you can register to listen to

> UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification

which can be seen here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

If you want to overcome the possibility of the device being orientation locked, then you have to manually monitor the accelerometer of the device.

In a game where orientation is essential, manually monitoring is recommended, since the first method has a little delay.

Comment: thanks for your  reply, that was some really useful info :). I was planning to follow the second method only but doesnt it need the accelerometer value to be checked every frame?  will it affect the performance?

Comment: Yes and hit on the iphones battery life very heavely, what games do is play with the rate of update from either the motion manager or accelerometer. if your purpose is only for hud orientation use the device orientation. if you have some in game interaction with how the device is being held then you have no choice. you can easely set a timer to read it, DO NOT place it every frame, since you will notice how alot of the time your readings will be the same. create an independent timer.

Comment: ya fine it is much clear now. Thanks again.     btw it is only for HUD  so i would go for the callbacks itslef. And ya i would follw the timer trick and not every frame method when i require.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is this:

In your `didfinishlaunching` write this

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:)
    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];`

and then copy the following callback method

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{   
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        NSLog(@"Landscape Left!");
        self.isLandscapeLeft=1;
    }else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
         NSLog(@"Landscape Right!");
        self.isLandscapeLeft=0;
    }
}
```

Likewise you can check orientation for potrait mode,face-up,face-down,upside down and landscapeleft and landscape right orientation.:)